# Facebook Messenger repeats sending user input

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have Facebook Messenger set up with a chatbot in PHP.
I am breaking up what would normally be a single response into multiple reply messages so that it looks more natural in a chat and easier to read than a single large chat bubble.

Here is how I am doing that:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($response_array); $i++){
     $message_fb_format = [
         'recipient' => [
             'id' => $userID,
         ],
         'message' => [
             'text' => $response_array[$i],
        ],
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $replyMessageJSON);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Hub-Signature: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 'CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION_NONE');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    sleep(2);
}
```

I found that when I set `sleep()` to 2 seconds or more, Facebook Messenger repeats sending the original user input. The chat window then appears as if my chatbot repeats its responses many times to a single input, but my logs clearly show that my server is receiving the same message from Facebook many times and the chatbot is responding correctly to each one.

Question is, why?
**Why does a 2 second pause between multiple response messages cause Facebook Messenger to repeat the sending of the original message?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they expect you to respond to the webhook request with a `200 OK` in a timely manner, and otherwise assume something must have gone wrong, that your bot was notable to receive the send data, and so it gets send again.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#unsubscribe

You would have to answer the incoming webhook request first with 200 OK and the first reply, and then send your additional messages to the recipient afterwards, independently from that initial request. (Only with Standard Messaging you won’t be able to do that in an unlimited way, because of the “24 + 1” policy.)

Comment: Because x times 2 seconds is longer than just x times 1 second?

Comment: There is only _one_ HTTP response, and you are delaying that HTTP response by x times 2 seconds.

Comment: _“ adding 200 OK alone did not solve it”_ - this is about the response your webhook script gives. Sending a `200 OK` with your cURL API calls is something completely different. (And nonsensical; `200 OK` is a response header, sending it with a request makes no sense to begin with.)

Comment: OK so I'm obviously missing something, so when you say "You would have to answer the incoming webhook request first with 200 OK and the first reply" in your answer, can you expand how do I do that if not through curl?

Comment: The incoming webhook request is the one that calls your PHP script that you have shown above - _that_ request has to be answered with a 200 OK response in a timely manner. PHP by default sends a 200 OK, but only when the script has ended. So by sleeping between your (rather unrelated) cURL requests, you are delaying that response. PHP in theory has the ability to send response headers earlier (keyword `flush`), but how well that works in practice depends on other factors as well (webserver, etc.) Go do some research into that if you want to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook's documentation, You have to respond to any request within 20 seconds.

> When you receive a webhook event, you must always return a 200 OK HTTP response. The Messenger Platform will resend the webhook event every 20 seconds, until a 200 OK response is received. Failing to return a 200 OK may cause your webhook to be unsubscribed by the Messenger Platform.

You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#response

May be when lots of response comes, the queue becomes large and it keeps periodically repeating the same response again and again. 
Make sure you respond within 20 seconds.